# file permissions for the same user on 2 different computers

Tags: windows, permissions

I'm trying to change file permissions on a windows server for a domain. It works fine except for one little problem. There is a co-worker that logs in using the same user as mine but on my computer I have full file permissions and on hers the file is read-only. Any help?

Comment: Do you have the file open when she opens it?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all child object permission for Web User and Network Service of your Domain.

If permission is not given properly or not propogated proper then this should be happened.